# Scaling down the keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet, timeline

I'm trying to understand how to stretch and scale exactly the keyframes of my animation. Let's say that at the beginning my animation was composed by 66 frames that I want to render at 24 fps. Later I stretched the keyframes to 110 because the character's movements was too robotic. Now I want to come back to 66. I gone to frame 1 on the dope sheet and I scaled down the frames a little,but the position of the characters is not aligned with the background images that I used on the beginning to make the poses. I need to understand what's the method to know exactly how many frames should I add to 66 the make a fluid animation at 24 fps and how can I scale the frames from 110 to 66 to match the starting background images. Check [here](https://sendvid.com/el2pl3pc) to see what happened when I tried to scale down the frames. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the animation editor, position the 2D cursor to the frame you want to use as the "origin" for your scale operation (probably the first frame of the animation) and set the pivot point to "2D Cursor".

Select the keyframes you want to scale. Press <kbd>s</kbd> to scale, <kbd>x</kbd> to scale on the x-axis (time), then type 66, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then press <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, then type 110/ to scale by 1/110, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply. This will scale your keyframes' timekeys by a factor of 66/110.

The keyframes will probably not align perfectly with entire frames. Blender's interpolation system can handle this just fine. If you want, you can snap them to entire frames by pressing <kbd>Shift+S</kbd> and choosing "Nearest Frame".

Comment: The keyframes of my animation are 200,excuse me for the mistake. But anyway,I tried to scale them as you have suggested pressing S ; X ; and then I wrote 0.33 (66/200),as you can see here : https://sendvid.com/9naw83ni ; but it didn't work.

Comment: A blender guru says : "The thing is, scaling frames back and forward in dope sheet is not a way to go, cause frames are like integers, you can't have 1.5 or 1.2 frames, you just have 1,2,3 - whole numbers of frames, so if you scaled it up x2, the distances between frames had doubled (not distance between first frame and them but between them), if you remember that - it's ok, you can go and make s, 0.5 and you land with the same frame setup, but if you don't and make s,0.3 for example, then you're ending up with total mess". What do you think ?

Comment: @Marietto F-Secure says "This web site has been reported as harmful.
We recommend that you do not visit this web site" -- I can't watch your video. I'll update my answer, though.

Comment: I think that it is a false positive. I never heard that sendvid is harmful.

Comment: Just for others that were confused like me - "2D cursor" is just the current spot in the timeline (i.e., the vertical bar indicating which frame is being previewed). Also, the option to change scaling reference is on the top right of the window.

Comment: The "2D cursor" also includes the value, so it's the intersection point between the vertical line (current frame) and the horizontal line (the value).