# Applying scale on the armature messes up whole animation, How to apply scale on Armature correctly?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, scale

I imported a mixamo character in blender 2.83. Its armature scale is set to 0.01.I want to apply this scale (Ctrl+A).

[image]

But whenever I apply the scale, the armature and mesh changes it location and the animation becomes all messed up.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149139/how-do-i-scale-a-skeleton-down-with-out-affecting-the-animation-time-the-locat  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80816/scaling-down-the-keyframes  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96982/how-do-i-scale-without-loosing-my-animation

Comment: It does pretty much but i don't understand what it meant to remove the scale keys separately in the answer, like delete or lock or something else.If you could explain a bit please

Comment: He means deleting the keyframes which exist on the scale channels only. With the scale keyframes removed, they cannot interpolate as the animation plays. Like any other situation in animation, if there are no keyframes on a channel, you can set its value wherever you want, and it will stay there. No keyframes will interfere with where you set the value, because there aren't any keyframes.